# R XPath text after sibling

Tags: r, xpath

I'd like to pick from this html:

```
doc <- htmlParse("http://eusoils.jrc.ec.europa.eu/ESDB_Archive/ESDBv3/legend/sg_attr.htm")
```

but I have some issues with special characters (i.e. > and < signs) and get different lengths of nodes, see here:

```
legs <- getNodeSet(doc, "//a")
leg_names <- sapply(legs, xmlGetAttr, "name")
leg_descr <- xpathSApply(doc, "//strong", xmlValue)

# not the same length??
cbind(leg_names, leg_descr)

# different length??
getNodeSet(doc, '//text()[following-sibling::a]')
```

and

```
# why is this not working?
getNodeSet(doc, '//a[@name="AGLIM1"]/text()[following-sibling::strong')
```

in the end I'd like to have every legend (text after the a tags with a certain name) in a table with two columns, the 1st with the value/symbol the 2nd with the label for it..

**Like this one for WRB-FULL:**

```
     Value                  Label
        AB            Albeluvisol
      ABal       Alic Albeluvisol
      ABap   Abruptic Albeluvisol
      ABar     Arenic Albeluvisol
      ABau     Alumic Albeluvisol
     ABeun Endoeutric Albeluvisol
       ...        ...         ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formatting of the document is not consistent:
there are `<a>` elements without a following `<strong>` element -- 
so there are more of the former.

```
cbind( head(leg_names,8), head(leg_descr,8) )
     [,1]            [,2]                                                                                                    
# [1,] "AGLIM1"        "AGLIM1: Code of the most important limitation to agricultural use of the STU"                          
# [2,] "AGLIM2"        "AGLIM2: Code of a secondary limitation to agricultural use of the STU"                                 
# [3,] "BORDER_SOIL1M" "FAO85-FULL: Full Soil Code 1974 FAO"                                                                   
# [4,] "SOIL1M"        "FAO85-LEV1: Soil major group code of the STU from the 1974 (modified CEC 1985) FAO-UNESCO Soil Legend" 
# [5,] "CFL"           "FAO85-LEV2: Second level soil code of the STU from the 1974 (modified CEC 1985) FAO-UNESCO Soil Legend"
# [6,] "CL"            "FAO85-LEV3: Third level soil code of the STU from the 1974 (modified CEC 1985) FAO-UNESCO Soil Legend" 
# [7,] "COUNTRY"       "FAO90-FULL:Full soil code of the STU from the 1990 FAO-UNESCO Soil Legend"                             
# [8,] "FAO85FU"       "FAO90-LEV1: Soil major group code of the STU from the 1990 FAO-UNESCO Soil Legend"
```

The `following-sibling` approach seems more promising, but since there are `<a>` elements not followed immediately with a `<strong>` element, you can end up with the description of another element.

```
getNodeSet(doc, '//a[@name="AGLIM1"]/following-sibling::strong/text()')[[1]]
```

An alternative would be to forget the formatting and consider the file as a text file.

```
raw_data <- readLines("http://eusoils.jrc.ec.europa.eu/ESDB_Archive/ESDBv3/legend/sg_attr.htm")
library(stringr)
matches <- str_extract(raw_data, '<a .*<strong>.*')
matches <- matches[ ! is.na(matches) ]
result <- str_match(matches, '<a name="(.*?)".*<strong>(.*)</strong>')[,-1]
head(result)
     [,1]       [,2]                                                                                                    
[1,] "AGLIM1"   "AGLIM1: Code of the most important limitation to agricultural use of the STU"                          
[2,] "AGLIM2"   "AGLIM2: Code of a secondary limitation to agricultural use of the STU"                                 
[3,] "FAO85FU"  "FAO85-FULL: Full Soil Code 1974 FAO"                                                                   
[4,] "FAO85LV1" "FAO85-LEV1: Soil major group code of the STU from the 1974 (modified CEC 1985) FAO-UNESCO Soil Legend" 
[5,] "FAO85LV2" "FAO85-LEV2: Second level soil code of the STU from the 1974 (modified CEC 1985) FAO-UNESCO Soil Legend"
[6,] "FAO85LV3" "FAO85-LEV3: Third level soil code of the STU from the 1974 (modified CEC 1985) FAO-UNESCO Soil Legend"
```

Comment: Thanks, I see. Do you have an idea how to get the desired result, like in the example df that I added to the question?

Comment: Since the data is not formatted in a consistent way,
it seems dangerous to try to automatically parse this file:
the fields are sometimes separated by spaces, sometimes by `=`,
sometimes by `:`, sometimes indentified by their position 
(because they can be empty and/or contain spaces),
which is never the same.
It will be faster, and safer, to do it by hand...